# External image not displaying in community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, images, http

My problem is that I cannot view an image loaded from an external site into an img tag in my lightning component. The URL is with 'http' protocol not 'https', but when I see the Chrome Console, it tells that failed to load resource and I noticed that Salesforce try to go to the external site with the 'https' protocol and so it not find the resource. Why all this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to settings > search for Remote Site Settings, click New Remote Site > Give it a Name, type in the FULL URL of the image including the 'http://'
BE SURE to check the box: Disable Protocol Security since this is not an 'https', make it active and try your image then
Good luck!

Comment: I have several images to show. Can I only add the domain to the whitelist? Why you say to add the full URL?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, just the domain works. I said FULL meaning include http

Comment: Also, if Remote Sites doesn't work you can try adding it to CSP Trusted Sites. CSP just doesn't give you the option of Disabling Protocol Security

Comment: I tried to add the domain to remote sites, but nothing changed. If it can be a plus, the component is shown into a community. Can this be a problem?

Comment: I have not used Community before, I am not sure if that's the issue. Have you tried other browsers? Any chance you get your HTTP site changed to HTTPS?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213361&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: yes, when I check the console it says can't find the resource at 'https' not 'http' (but the link use 'http'). Can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

As @ryangreene has commented in a different answer the solution may be found in https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334127&type=1&mode=1

> Chrome has a security feature to block insecure content (HTTP) which
>   is being loaded via a secure page (HTTPS). In order to avoid this
>   error, the content being loaded must be in secure form (HTTPS).

How to bypass the Chrome limitation could be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content

Answer (score 1):

This helped me

1. Go to **Settings**->**Security** in Experience Builder
2. Choose *"Allow Inline Scripts and Script Access to Whitelisted Third-party Hosts"*
3. Add the sites in *Trusted Sites for Scripts* part

Reference:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_security_csp_scriptlevel.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

If you are displaying those images from *Static Resources*.
Then you don't have to include 'https'.
Simply go to your Static Resources > Your resource file (image) > click on View FIle link
And copy the URL from /resource/....

And your `<IMG>` will look like this => `<img src='/resource/1638263749/Your_Logo?'/>`

Comment: While this is helpful for those displaying images from *Static Resources*, this does not answer the original question where the title and question both explicitly concern image(s) from an *external* site.